# How would I start learning how to program in Flex?

Tags: apache-flex

Can anyone give me pointers to good books or web sites that teach how to do Flex programming?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Check out [Ten Great Ways to Learn Flex](http://joshblog.net/2007/04/05/ten-ways-beginners-can-learn-adobe-flex/), but I think number one should be to use the [Quickstarts on the Adobe Site](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/?tab:quickstart=1).

Answer (score 16):

**[Flex in a Week](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/videotraining/) Video Training** on Adobe's site.

*"Learn Flex in a week by going through this video training course. To maximize your learning, we recommend that you view the videos and complete the exercises in the order that they are listed. If you run into problems and have questions, you can ask a question on the Flex in a Week forum."*

- Day 1: Flex basics
- Day 2: Component development
- Day 3: Putting it all together
- Day 4: Adding visual appeal
- Day 5: Architecture and advanced topics

Answer (score 4):

noone mentioned [FlexExamples](http://blog.flexexamples.com/)

When I was working on a first flex project this resource helped alot to understand many things. The difference about it is, it has examples which is more required when you're developing application. It surely help you in many ways.

Answer (score 3):

A book we used in class that is a free download from adobe:
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/pdfs/getting_started_with_Flex3.pdf

Answer (score 2):

lynda.com has [a set of Flex videos](http://movielibrary.lynda.com/html/modListing.asp?pid=205), including [basic Flex 3](http://movielibrary.lynda.com/html/modPage.asp?ID=438), [advanced topics](http://movielibrary.lynda.com/html/modPage.asp?ID=437), and [AIR Essentials](http://movielibrary.lynda.com/html/modPage.asp?ID=542).

It's a subscription site, but for $250 a year, if you use other Adobe products like [ColdFusion 8](http://movielibrary.lynda.com/html/modListing.asp?pid=274) or the new [CS 4](http://movielibrary.lynda.com/html/modListing.asp?pid=362) (they have plenty of CS 3 videos too), it's easily worth it.